# Elasticsearch - Case insensitive aggregation not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

ES version - **7.17.7**

I've an index for which I' running an aggregation to get all field matching certain regex. This should be case-insensitive i.e.

```
new york should match New York and NEW YORK and New YORK
```

Have added a `lowercase_normaliser` to index so that documents are indexed with lowercase name. This doesn't solve the issue though.
Now I've to pass the regex in lowercase, else it doesn't return correct results.

I've created an index named **blah** with following mapping

```
{
  "blah": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index settings -

```
{
  "blah": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "max_ngram_diff": "20",
        "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
            "lowercase_normalizer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documents inserted:

**blah/_doc/1**

```
{
  "name": "NEW YORK"
}
```

**blah/_doc/2**

```
{
  "name": "New Orleans"
}
```

**blah/_doc/3**

```
{
  "name": "New Hampshire"
}
```

Following aggregation query doesn't return expected results -
**Query**

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "autoComplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.raw",
        "include": "New.*",
        "order": [
          {
            "_term": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

**Output**

```
  "aggregations": {
    "autoComplete": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [

      ]
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**
Another downside is that if  I use aggregation after running `.lowecase` on `inlcude` value, results are also normalised. Is it possible to have original value being returned?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try search analyzer.
For more details follow this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-analyzer.html

Comment: `search_analyzer` is not a parameter of `type=keyword` and cannot be used for aggregation. Can you add snippet on how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you replace lines with `"include": "new.*"` (terms have been already lowercased) and with `"_key": "asc"` in query